# How Can I rearrange Listview with mouse in C#

Tags: c#

How can I rearrange a listview with mouse in C#? I have a lisview filled with image names and I'm doing a slidewhow program.

I want to rearrange the image order by using listview. How can I do that ?

Comment: I suggest you to use kind of jquery based plugin for producing this kind of behavior.

Comment: This seems to cover it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443695/how-do-i-drag-drop-items-in-the-same-listview

Answer (score 0):

You should handle mouse events. On MouseDown, you should get selected image. On MouseMove, you should reorder the images based on mouse location. On MouseUp, you should end this operation.

Comment: Could you give some example code for this ? if you could that would be great becasue I'm very new at this.