# ListView size changes whilst dragging an item to the bounds of it

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

This is hard to describe in words exactly what the problem is, so I have provided a gif of the issue to hopefully get it across.

link to image:
https://gyazo.com/00ed9cd3e1f2cf377f45e13737fcfc8e

If I disable the scrolling of the frame this does not happen, however this ListView needs to scroll for the entire program to function well.

I have thought about writing my own ListView like system using System.Drawing with panels but I decided to come here first to find a solution that might be less time consuming.

Is there any way I can stop the size from changing when items are moved against the boundaries of the form?

EDIT:
Here's the code for dragging an item:

```
    private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = e.Item as ListViewItem;
        itemStartPos = item.Position;
        mouseStartPos = Control.MousePosition;
        this.DoDragDrop(item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = e.Item as ListViewItem;
        itemStartPos = item.Position;
        mouseStartPos = Control.MousePosition;
        this.DoDragDrop(item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem)) != null)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }

    private void listView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem)) as ListViewItem; 
        if(item != null)
        {
            Point mousePos = Control.MousePosition;
            Point itemPos = new Point(itemStartPos.X + mousePos.X - mouseStartPos.X, itemStartPos.Y + mousePos.Y - mouseStartPos.Y);
            item.Position = itemPos;
        }
    }

    private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //Save pos to registry for loading it back in 
    }
```

(hope this formats properly)

The user should be able to freely drag any item within the listview and drop it at the location the release the item at.

Comment: Looks funny. Is there any code to show us?

Comment: Yeah sure I'll add the dragging code to an edit

Comment: Have you verified what [Control.MousePosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition) actually returns?

Comment: I'm certain that it does return since it does set the position of the item to where the mouse is, however I will double check

Comment: In relation to what coordinates system? (Yes, it does *return something*, verify what coordinates the Point it returns refers to).

Comment: yes it does return

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, I believe you are referring to what the coordinates are relative to which in that case they are relative to the full screen

Comment: Right, now, `ListViewItem.Position`, to what coordinates system refers to? Try something like this instead: [How to drag & drop items in the same ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9445585/7444103)

Comment: But also take a look at [ListView.InsertionMark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.insertionmark)

Comment: alright I'll take a look there

Comment: It seems that while helpful resources these suggestions do not produce the effect I wish to achieve as shown within the gif provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an interesting fix to this issue that may only pertain to my specific program but I'll give this question closure.

When the **ItemDrag** event is called I set the scrollable propety to false, and when **DragDrop** is called it is set back to true. The reason I say this may only pertain to my program specifically is because when a user drags something the positions are saved to the registry and then subsequently reloaded after the scrollable property is set to true. You see, when the scrollable property is changed it redraws the entire listview so I had to do a bit of a funky work around.